# TCL TWAPI - Replacing strings in Word Document

Tags: replace, ms-word, tcl, word-interop

I began using twapi for COM connections and like it very much so far. However, the documentation for interfacing of particular Office-packages is sort of weak (at least for me :) ) or lost over the years. My current problem is a very small one, but still, I'm stuck. (To say it just beforehand: pointing out any serious documentation for twapi usage would be really really helpful and appreciated)

I want to do a simple 'find and replace' in a Word-Document.

The VB code for this could look like this:

```
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content 
    With myRange.Find 
     .ClearFormatting 
     .Replacement.ClearFormatting 
     .Text = "Hello" 
     .Replacement.Text = "Goodbye" 
     .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 
    End With
```

Since it seems, that calling down the object tree in one shot is not possible in TCL, i tried this, to break it down to TCL:

```
    proc Word_FindAndReplace { doc  cSearch cReplace} { 

        try {

            set content [$doc Content]
            set find [$content Find]
            set repl [$find Replacement]
            $find ClearFormatting
            $repl ClearFormatting
            $find Text $cSearch
            $repl Text $cReplace
            #wdReplaceAll   2   ;#replace all
            $find Execute Replace 2   ;#   <-----not working
            return 1

        } on error {msg} {

            puts stderr "$msg $::errorInfo $::errorCode"
            return -1

        }

    }
```

The final "$find Execute Replace 2" is the culprit. Everything else just works fine. It seems that calling the "Execute" in the last line requires a special parameter format, but I don't know it.
Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: you should use [cawt](https://www.tcl3d.org/cawt/) based on Twapi

Comment: I had hoped to not get a recommendation for cawt :). Thank you for your comment. It is more complicated. It has to do with... cleaning up the work environment, where once was a jungle like mixture of 32 and 64 bit libs, using anything that comes in the way, which at one point made it hard to maintain. We're narrowing down to libs, that are available in both 64 and 32 bit (which is true for cawt as well) and to few and strong ones. We already brought many programs to twapi already and from the office packages is just the word part the only one left. If possible we want like to stick with twapi.

Comment: I found a solution in the meantime. Would have been interesting to know, how the question above would have been answered (could become handy in the future...), but I could find a solution in a C# example. Find is able to receive _all_ possible parameters at once, so replacing the upper line in question with the following:
$find Execute $cSearch 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 $cReplace 2 0 0 0 0
solves my problem. It works! :)

Answer (score 0):

See comments please. The answer to the original question would still be good to know, since I suspect, it will come up in other places with twapi, but the current problem could be worked around. "Find" accepts all possible parameters at once (15 all in all), so the line

```
    $find Execute $cSearch 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 $cReplace 2 0 0 0 0
```

solves my current problem.